# Salesforce: Possible to use "describeLayout" function from REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, salesforce, databasedotcom-gem

I know `describeLayout` is accessible from the SOAP API, but is it possible to access it from the REST API as well? I'm particularly interested in accessing this function using the [databasedotcom](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom) Ruby gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the rest API doesn't currently have an equivalent of the describeLayout call in the SOAP API.